# $X = C[0,1]$, $Y = C[a,b]$, $T: X \to Y$ isomorphism, can it be injective?

Tags: functional-analysis

$X = C[0,1]$, $Y = C[a,b]$, $T: X \to Y$ isomorphism, can it be injective?

This isomorphism is just a change of variables of the form:
$$ f(t) \to f(at+b)$$

It is surjective and it satisfies: 
$$ \Vert Tx \Vert = \Vert x \Vert $$

I need to say if it can also be injective.

I do not think it can, so I want to prove it by contradiction:
If it was then T would be an homomorphism, I want to say something regarding the two spaces but I am struggling to find the contradiction.

Comment: It is a linear map with trivial kernel...indeed $F[f](x)=f(g(x))$ is always injective when $g$ is.

Comment: I do not think I am following you.

Comment: A linear mapping between vector spaces is injective if and only if its kernel contains only the zero vector of its domain.